# \input with wildcards (regex) in the file name

Tags: input

I would like to `\input` all tex-files in a certain directory starting with "prefix", in alphabetical order.
Something like `\input{prefix*tex}` would be nice, but it doesn't work.

Is there some workaround?

Answer (score 4):

I would use your operating system, so for exanple

```
 ls prefix*tex | sed -e 's/\(.*\)/\\input{\1}/' > list-prefix.tex
 pdflatex main
```

will make a file `list-prefix.tex` with one `\input{..}` per line, for
each file matching `prefix*.tex`.

will input all the files if `main.tex` has `\input{list-prefix}` at some point.

If you only need to input (and never add headings etc, and want to avoid making 
a temporary file, you can use

```
\input{"|cat prefix*.tex"}
```

but then you have to process your `main.tex` with `pdflatex --shell-escape` or equivalent.

I've used unix shell commands here but the same works on windows if you substitute the appropriate commands (or use bash on windows, which is what I do personally)

Answer (score 1):

You have of course to use the shell escape, because TeX has no wild card capability.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{xparse}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand{\xinput}{m}{%
  \azimut_xinput:n { #1 }
}

\ior_new:N \g_azimut_xinput_stream

\cs_new_protected:Nn \azimut_xinput:n
 {
  \ior_open:Nn \g_azimut_xinput_stream { "|ls ~ #1" }
  \ior_map_inline:Nn \g_azimut_xinput_stream { \file_input:n { \tl_trim_spaces:n {##1} } }
 }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\xinput{az-*.tex}

\end{document}
```

The `ls` command on Unix systems return the file list one element per line, so we can map the lines to `\file_input:n`.

You have to run this with

```
pdflatex -shell-escape
```

On Windows system the command to use might be different from `ls`.

I tested it with three files, `az-a.tex`, `az-b.tex` and `az-c.tex`. This is the terminal output showing that the files have been input.

```
(./azimut.aux) (./az-a.tex) (./az-b.tex) (./az-c.tex) [1{/usr/local/texlive/201
4/texmf-var/fonts/map/pdftex/updmap/pdftex.map}] (./azimut.aux) )</usr/local/te
xlive/2014/texmf-dist/fonts/type1/public/amsfonts/cm/cmr10.pfb>
Output written on azimut.pdf (1 page, 10198 bytes).
```

This can easily be extended to do more things; for instance, you may want to type the file name:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{xparse}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand{\xinput}{m}{%
  \azimut_xinput:n { #1 }
}

\ior_new:N \g_azimut_xinput_stream

\cs_new_protected:Nn \azimut_xinput:n
 {
  \ior_open:Nn \g_azimut_xinput_stream { "|ls ~ #1" }
  \ior_map_inline:Nn \g_azimut_xinput_stream
   {
    \par\noindent\texttt{##1}\par\nopagebreak
    \file_input:n { \tl_trim_spaces:n {##1} }
    }
 }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\xinput{az-*.tex}

\end{document}
```

[image]

The files just contain one letter, for the sake of the example.