# Regarding \input and for loop in Latex

Tags: pdftex, latex3

I have 179 TeX files present inside a folder called Commands.
Now there is a main.tex file in which I've used 179 times `\input{Commands/*.tex}` to invoke all 179 files.
How can I use for loop here to invoke all `.tex` files.
I've files named as `001_abc.tex`, `002_def.tex`, `003_sjs.tex`, `004_jdj.tex`, …, `179_dsh.tex`.

Comment: as your files don't only differ by number you need access to a directory listing so this is a duplicate of https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/245540/input-with-wildcards-regex-in-the-file-name/245546#245546

Comment: @egreg ? I did, the exact pattern differs but same answer applies, just starting with `ls [0-9]*_*.tex`  rather than `ls prefix*.tex`